# Im going to a 1x is there a freewheel with more than 34 t on the large gear/cog?

Tags: shimano

My problem is that I'm going to a 1x I need more than 34 teeth on my large gear cog does any know of a freewhee with more than 34 teeth on the largest gear cog on a freewheel?

Comment: Sure - you can go up to 50-60 tooth on the dinner-plate sized ones.  But the question really needs to state what derailleur you have, in order to calculate the maximum chain takeup and thus the tooth count difference.  What is the make and model of your rear derailleur ?

Comment: @Criggie he's asking about freewheels, and those 50t cogs tend to be on cassettes.

Comment: @pacomiller Excellent point - can you also confirm if your bike's rear wheel needs a freewheel or has a freehub that uses a cassette ?

Comment: Yes its freewheel ,thx criggie the arbitrary example you gave me I think is exactly what I'm running,shimano tourney, that stuff will be gone off the bike soon,Im going to post another qwestion and I'm also goona try and fine the answer my self ,thx again criggie and ojs

Comment: GAAAH, _don't_ do this, _why_?? Freewheels are bad enough with a 3×, why would you put any effort into making this 1× just to get a bike that doesn't have a good gear range _and_ will have its axle broken from just looking at it in an edgy way?

Comment: You may look at a new rear wheel and the new Box Four 1x8, that may be the cheapest route if you are set on 1x

Answer (score 3):

The largest freewheel I found was a 10 speed with 14-36 teeth, or Shimano's "megarange" ones that generally go 14-32 or 14-34.

The rear mech will probably have a model on it.  Searching for "brand model spec" will often give you a manufacturer's specifications page.  To use an arbitrary example, a **Shimano Tourney RD-TY300-SGS**  google returns https://bike.shimano.com/en-NZ/product/component/tourney/RD-TY300-SGS.html

That page says in part:

| Item | Value | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Low sprocket_Max. | 34T | The biggest cog should be no-larger than 34 tooth |
| Low sprocket_Min. | 28T | and no smaller than 28 tooth |
| Max. front difference | 20T | Not relevant to a 1x drivetrain |
| Top sprocket_Max. | 14T | The smallest/hardest cog must be 11-14 tooth |
| Top sprocket_Min. | 11T |  |
| Total capacity | 43T | And this is also irrelevant to a 1x |

Aside - your rear derailleur doesn't care if you have a freewheel or a cassette on a freehub.  But it has to match the rear wheel's fitment.

So find your model, search for the specs, and see what its capable of.  You may choose to push the published stats by a little, and probably get away with it.  Something rated 34T will probably be fine at 36T, but 40 would be pushing it.   50 is right out.

---

Instead of going big at the back, you can also choose a smaller chainring at the front, with the natural consequence of not having a high-enough gear for a big-tailwind or a downhill.

Another option is to have two 1-by chainrings, and use a mechanical system to change from one 1by to the other 1by.  I've heard its possible to have three 1by chainrings on the same bike, potentially giving a sub-1:1 gear ratio at the lowest gearings.

<sup>Seriously though, there's no shame in a double or even a triple chainring if you ride a lot of hills, or even just the occasional steep one.</sup>

Comment: Awesome, thanks criggie,and ojs,nice

Comment: All I ride is hills,thx

Comment: @Pacomiller then go for a smaller chainring.  It saves weight too, nice for climbing.

Answer (score 2):

The largest freewheel cog/sprocket I ever found and used on my touring tandem was 38 tooth.  I spent one year touring the U.S.A. on my tandem from October 10, 1981 to late summer 1982.  I used a 27-1x3/8" tire, custom-made tandem with quad crank of 16t, 24t, 42t, 52t.  The lowest gear was 13.5".  I easily road over grand teton pass and over 13,000 miles.